# How to add days to specified date based on this code

Tags: java, android

for adding days to specific date i tried like this

```
calendar.setTime(currentDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
Date nextWeek = calendar.getTime();
System.out.format("next week:  %s\n", nextWeek);
```

but i am using this to get app installed date

```
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(
                        "com.mothistorycheck.functions", 0);
                String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
                long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();
                Date date = new Date(installed * 1000L);
                Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

i want to get 1 year ahead date from this installed date ,how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming normal java here (and that the appFile is an up to date value)

```
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    long lastMod = f.lastModified();
    System.out.println("last mod: "+lastMod);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(lastMod);
    System.out.println("date: "+c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    System.out.println("new date:"+c.getTime());
```

output:
last mod: 1382558398000
date: Thu Oct 24 08:26:47 CDT 2013
new date:Fri Oct 24 08:26:47 CDT 2014

Comment: Here you are adding one year to current date not installed date.

Comment: Sorry good point .. add  c.setTimeInMillis(lastMod); after creating 'c'.. Source updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.mothistorycheck.functions", 0);
String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
File file = new File(appFile);
Date installed = new Date(file.lastModified());


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(installed);
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
Date installedPlusYear = calendar.getTime();
```